# How to remove the blurry effect around the player in Minecraft RTX?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, graphics-card, minecraft-rtx

Whenever I play on Minecraft (Bedrock edition) for Windows 10 with Ray Tracing turned on, I have a weird blurry effect that appears starting from 4-5 blocks away from me. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As I said, this feels odd and doesn't look good at all. When playing with RTX turned off, this effect disappears entirely. I asked how to disable this blurry effect first on the official Minecraft Discord server, and someone answered me and said I should look through the Nvidia Control Panel, so I did. I tried changing some of the 3D settings, such as antialiasing, but nothing worked. The blurry effect would still be there no matter what. So here's my question: How to disable this blurry effect? (I own an RTX 3060 if this help)

EDIT: This blurry effect seems to only appears with grass blocks.

Comment: Are there any graphics settings either called "Post-processing effects" or "depth of field"? If there are, could you try turning those off?

Comment: Probably irrelevant but the fact that you look like you have your FOV set to Quake Pro is DISGOOSTIN

Comment: @Lexibutt I didn't find anything called this way sadly...

Comment: @Penguin This isn't even quake pro, it's also some weird hand rendering due to Ray Tracing too ahah.